# How to use jQuery load to fetch products for an ecommerce website

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to create an AJAX feature for an ecommerce website built on asp.net web forms. In this AJAX feature I have to load products from the database and show in my page.

I am using **jQuery** Load method for making the AJAX call. I know how to use the .load() method but I am bit confused about how it will fetch the products from database.

The main problem here is that I have to pass 2 parameters to filter the products. These are "product keyword" and "product category". So please guide me in creating this feature from jQuery Load Method.

Thank you

Comment: why not just use an `ajax` `post` and pass the data through that? Also have you read the documentation?

Comment: You can pass data as `$.load('serversidemedthod',{'product_keyword':'somekeyword','product_category':'somecategory'},function(){....})`. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: thank you GuruprasadRao now i understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly use jQuery Load method to fetch your products from the database. For this you 
make the AJAX call from jQuery Load from page 1 to page 2.

**Page 1:**
Add a div with id "resultDiv".

```
<div id="resultDiv"></div>
```

In this div the products will be fecthed from jQuery load method and shown.

Then add the load method code like this:

```
$("#resultDiv").load("page2.aspx #productData", { "keyword": "" + $("#keywordInput").val() + "", "category": "" + $("#categorySelect").val() + "" }, function (response, status, xhr) {
    if (status == "error")
        alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
});
```

The "productData" will be a div in page2 and jQuery load will fetch its content. In the second parameter of load() function I am passing the keywords and category.

You can imaging here that "keywordInput" can be a text box while "categorySelect" can be a select control. User adds his keyword on the text box and selects the category ,then he can press a submit button. The click event of the button is where jQuer Load code will be written.

Page 2:
Add a div "productData" in the page:

```
<div id="productData" runat="server"></div>
```

On this .cs page inside the Page_load event you call a function & name it "FetchProduct".

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        FetchProduct();
    }
}
```

In the FetchProduct() you get the parameter keyword and parameter category value using Request.Form and then get products from database and show them inside the productData div. The code belwo explains this:

```
void FetchProduct()
{
    string keyword = Request.Form["keyword"];
    string category = Request.Form["category"];

    string information="";
    //get products form databaase then add them to information variable and show them inside productData div 
    productData.InnerHtml = information;
}
```

Now the productData will show the products but since page 2 is called by page 1 through jQuery Load therefore they will also show on page 1.

I would suggest you to see - this [**jQuery Load**](http://www.yogihosting.com/jquery-load/) method tutorial which explains some great ways to use .load() method in your websites.